# Можно ли отдельно выделить родительский класс из объекта в виде объекта?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Вопрос звучит немного странно, лучше показать в коде:

```
class class1
{
public:
    int x = 0;
};

class class2:class1
{
 public:
    int y = 0;
};
int main()
{
    class2 Obj2;
    class1 Obj1 = Obj2::class1;
}
```

Такое вообще возможно?  Если да, то как реализовать?

Можно сделать так, но мне не подходит

```
class class2
{
 public:
    class1 Obj1;
    int y = 0;
};
```

Comment: `class class2: public class1` и `class1 Obj1 = Obj2;`

Comment: Можно просто `class1 Obj1 = Obj2;`, эффект именно тот, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не забыть сделать наследование открытым

```
class class2: public class1
```

то проблема решается простым присваиванием/копированием

```
class2 Obj2;
class1 Obj1 = Obj2;
```

Каждый объект производного класса *является* объектом родительского, и это не пустые слова. Вы можете использовать объект производного класса везде, где используется объект родительского класса. При этом - если не передается указатель или ссылка - происходит *срезка* (slicing), т.е. все лишнее "отрезается", так что в `Obj1` вы получите только ту часть от `Obj2`, которая соответствует `class1`.